# Loop through nested json array to create new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I am working on a lambda function that `GET`s data from one API and `POST`s it to another. The data is a list of contacts with properties, e.g. first name, last name, email, etc.

The JSON output contains too many properties that I don't need. See below code example (actual code contains many more properties and nested arrays/objects).

```
{
  "contacts": [
      {
          "addedAt": 1532803458796,
          "vid": 101
      }
   ],
  "merge-audits": [],
  "properties": {
       "first-name": {
          "value":"hello"
        },
        "last-name": {
          "value":"there"
        },
        "email": {
          "value":"hello@there.com"
        }
... 
...
}
```

How can I loop through each JSON object to create a new, simpler JSON array like the following:

```
[
  {
    "email": "example@example.com",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "User"
  },
  {
    "email": "example2@example.com",
    "first_name": "Example",
    "last_name": "User"
  }
]
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: JSON is text. When you say "raw JSON" you seem to be really stressing it is JSON... but is it? Or are we starting out with a JavaScript object?

Comment: does your json have multiple keys called properties or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
json.map( x => ({
  email:      x.properties.email.value,
  first_name: x.properties['first-name'].value,
  last_name:  x.properties['last-name'].value,
}));
```

```js
let json = [
{
  "contacts": [{
    "addedAt": 1532803458796,
    "vid": 101
  }],
  "merge-audits": [],
  "properties": {
    "first-name": {
      "value": "hello"
    },
    "last-name": {
      "value": "there",
    },
    "email": {
      "value": "hello@there.com"
    }
  }
},
{
  "contacts": [{
    "addedAt": 1532803458796,
    "vid": 101
  }],
  "merge-audits": [],
  "properties": {
    "first-name": {
      "value": "Tom"
    },
    "last-name": {
      "value": "Smith",
    },
    "email": {
      "value": "tom@smith.com"
    }
  }
}
]

let r = json.map(x => ({
  email:      x.properties.email.value,
  first_name: x.properties['first-name'].value,
  last_name:  x.properties['last-name'].value,
}));

console.log(r);
```

Comment: Tested, worked perfectly and very efficient, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for the object and [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) for the mapping.

```js
var data = [{ contacts: [{ addedAt: 1532803458796, vid: 101 }], "merge-audits": [], properties: { "first-name": { value: "hello" }, "last-name": { value: "there" }, email: { value: "hello@there.com" } } }],
    result = data.map(({ properties: {
        'first-name': { value: first_name },
        'last-name': { value: last_name },
         email: { value: email }
    } }) => ({ first_name, last_name, email }));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your solution also produces the same results. Thank you for the additional information. Would this also work for multiple objects in the data variable?

Comment: it does, because data is an array and each same organized object gets converted.